# Is it possible to have a compile time check that a type is marked with the Serializable attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, session-state, compile-time

Specifically we're making our application compatible with the Out Of Process Session State server where all types saved in session must be serializable.

Is there a way to see at compile time that any type put into HttpSessionState is marked with the Serializable attribute.  Something along the lines of this 'non-valid' code

```
public static void Put<T>( string key, T value ) where T : IsMarkedWitheSerializableAttribute
{
   HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom FxCop rule to generate warnings for this scenario.

Jason Block has a sample rule on [his site](http://www.jasonbock.net/jb/Default.aspx?blog=entry.d6f6046800d945e6b94e8d92a4da52c2).

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no kind of generic constraint like that. Attributes are generally meant to indicate something about the *implementation* of a type. You'll have to either introduce your own marker interface (urgh) or insert an execution-time check and hope that your testing is sufficient.

[Eric Lippert's post about properties and attributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/02/properties-vs-attributes.aspx) is good to read here. It's not *quite* the same question, as it's talking more about objects vs types, but it's still relevant in terms of attributes expressing *mechanics*.

Comment: Is it the best pattern to use if I need interface with static members ? For example, I want to be able to instanciate ascx controls with a generic method, to be able to do 'var control = Page.LoadControl<MyControl>();' in place of 'var control = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");'. So I added a AscxPath attribute containing the path to my controls and an extension method on Page, the only thing I don't like about that is there's no compile time check.

Comment: @Guillaume86: It's not clear to me what the difference would be other than the lack of a cast, to be honest.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain very well, the static member i needed is the ascx path (controls are in different folders, the example is a simplification).

Comment: I just want to get rid of all these paths strings each time I instanciate a control (DRY).

Comment: @Guillaume86: Okay, I see what you mean. Can you use convention here, and work out the path name based on the type name? I've used that before and it's worked well.

Comment: At first I thought I couldn't since they are in different folders, but it looks like the namespaces could help me here, I can manage to guess the path with these informations, thanks